# C# Database for desktop without dll

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, dll

Im searching a database for C# without dll. 
I have using SQLite for my previous projects but this engine provided dll. 
I need new database engine without dll because my project should work only exe file.
I have examine SQLite download page and I could not find version without dll.
I may use XML file but I want database for speed. mssql, mysql provide dll and installation. db4o again provide dll.
Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need a database server that doesn't have any DLL's?

Comment: Use XML files. Seriously, you can search for source code and then compile the source code as part of your own program, but does it worth the effort? What is the problem with a DLL to add at your deployment?

Comment: Let your exe contain dll

Comment: [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) can store data in your.exe and you can use it as a database, but even this one is, unfortunately, hosted in `mscorlib.dll`...

Comment: To elaborate on what @DominikS said, you can use [Fody/Costura](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) to easily embed the sqlite dll inside your exe.

Comment: A file will be have a lot of records. Therefore xml option not good idea for my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deploy a single .exe file to the customer, consider merging all the dlls you used with ILMerge: it will create a single exe for you.

Trying to avoid dlls is impossible and cutting yourself out of practically every technology ever developed it's not a great idea :)

**Note**: ILMerge will merge only .NET libraries so you must switch from SQLITE to something like SQL Server CE (however SQL Server CE is really *better* than sqlite under many aspects).

Comment: Thank you bro.
I dont want merge dll to exe file. I should be compile library as static.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is built into windows. There is also a version of Sqlite that you can compile into your code.

Comment: I have researched sqlite cs files but i could not found. Is there file sqlite3? This file cannot compile : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs
Can you send me true files if you have.